# Polling in SFTP server (best way to copy new files from SFTP server to local machine at regular intervals)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sftp

I have one SFTP server. where there is no shell and only SFTP commands working.

However, there is a huge amount of files are there.

We have to copy recently arrived files from SFTP to my local Linux machine at regular interval of times (let's say 10 minutes).

Is there any way to achieve this

Thanks for any help !!

Comment: you want to download all files from your `sftp` server and keep your data uptodate ?

Comment: i need to copy only newly added files(in last 10 minute) from SFTP server to local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Since `sftp` has little option and you can't do what you want in just easy way using option or simple command the only solution i can see here to do what you want is to write a script to do this:

1. connect to server and run `ls -l` and get a list of details
2. filter the details in you local machine and extract the files name you want depending on the modify time, using `grep` for example
3. get the files that you want from the server

Maybe it's not the best solution but it's the only solution that i can see now